# How can I get different columns headers from the same columns but based on different filters?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to retrieve purchases made by clients on the last 40 days but putting in a different column also if it has a purchase on the last 20 days, and in a third column if they have any purchase prior the last 40 days.

I have a table like this (where LastPurchaseDate is a date field):

| ClientNumber | LastPurchaseDate |
| --- | --- |
| Account1 | Prior 40 days |
| Account2 | Last 40 days |
| Account3 | Last 20 days |
| Account4 | Last 40 days |
| Account2 | Prior 40 days |
| Account2 | Prior 40 days |

Basically I want to write a query that can give me a result like this:

| ClientNumber | Purchases on last 40 Days | Purchases on last 20 days | Purchases prior 40 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Account1 | NA | NA | 1 |
| Account2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Account3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Account4 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

So far I'm trying to do this using subqueries to get the info filtered by separate like this:

```
With Purchases40Days(
    select ClientNumber,
                           count(*) as PurchasesCount40Days
                          from Purchases 
                          where PurchaseDate > DATEADD('day', -40, CURRENT_DATE)
                          group by ClientNumber
)
With Purchases20Days(
    select ClientNumber,
                           count(*) as PurchasesCount20Days
                          from Purchases 
                          where PurchaseDate > DATEADD('day', -20, CURRENT_DATE)
                          group by ClientNumber
)
With PurchasesPrior40Days(
    select ClientNumber,
                           count(*) as PurchasesCountPrior40Days
                          from Purchases 
                          where PurchaseDate < DATEADD('day', -40, CURRENT_DATE)
                          group by ClientNumber
)

Select ClientNumber , 
p4.PurchasesCount40Days,
p2.PurchasesCount20Days,
pp4.PurchasesCountPrior40Days
from Client INNER JOIN Purchases40Days p4 on p4 .ClientNumber = Client.ClientNumber
INNER JOIN Purchases20Days p2 on p2 .ClientNumber = Client.ClientNumber
INNER JOIN PurchasesPrior40Days pp4 on pp4.ClientNumber = Client.ClientNumber
WHERE Client.Status = 'Active'
```

This is giving me only results that has a purchase on the last 40 days range, and also values older than 40 days on the count as long as they have at least one purchase on the last 40 days, but is not returning a value when no purchase on the last 40 days, so I think my third subquery is wrong or missing something?

Comment: Conditional aggregation - basically `select clientnumber, count(case when PurchaseDate > DATEADD('day', -40, CURRENT_DATE) then 1 else null end) as Purchases_on_last_40_Days,... from<table> group by CLientNumber`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
PIVOT (
    COUNT(LastPurchaseDate) 
    FOR LastPurchaseDate IN ('Prior 40 days', 'Last 40 days', 'Last 20 days')
) ;
```